# How do I replace the contents of an existing XML file in C#.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, file, locking

When trying to replace the content of an XML file in C#.NET with a snippet like this:

```
string file = Path.GetTempFileName(); // pretend this is a real file
string tmpFile = Path.GetTempFileName();

using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(File.Create(tmpFile)))
{
    writer.WriteStartElement("root");
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        writer.WriteElementString("test", null, 
            "All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy");
    }
    writer.WriteEndElement();
}

File.Delete(file);
File.Move(tmpFile, file);
```

... I get a System.IO.IOException claiming that the file is already opened by another process.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For some reason the XmlWriter class evidently does not dispose the underlying stream for the temporary file. Putting the stream in a "using" clause of its own makes sure the stream is closed correctly. Changing the code to

```
string file = Path.GetTempFileName(); // pretend this is a real file
string tmpFile = Path.GetTempFileName();

using (var stream = File.Create(tmpFile))
using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream))
{
    writer.WriteStartElement("root");
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        writer.WriteElementString("test", null, 
            "All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy");
    }
    writer.WriteEndElement();
}                
File.Delete(file);
File.Move(tmpFile,file);
```

... makes the IOException disappear and it works as intended.

Comment: Updated the answer with chained using statements as suggested by Greg D

Answer (score 4):

Using statements can be chained.  Slightly modifying your code:

```
string file = Path.GetTempFileName(); // pretend this is a real file
string tmpFile = Path.GetTempFileName();

using (var stream = File.Create(tmpFile))
using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream))
{
    writer.WriteStartElement("root");
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        writer.WriteElementString("test", null, 
            "All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy");
    }
    writer.WriteEndElement();
}                
File.Delete(file);
File.Move(tmpFile,file);
```

If you're dealing with multiple disposable entities over the same scope (not an uncommon occurrence), this avoids nastily deep nesting.  :)

Comment: Cool, I did not know that... I guess it is safe to assume that the using statments are closed in reverse order, i.e. the last disposable object is disposed of first?

Comment: Actually it's exactly the same thing as doing `using(A a = new A()) { using(B = new B()) { (do stuff) } }`. The outer `using` statement has exactly one statement inside it (namely the inner `using` statement).